# How can you make a CAEmitterLayer only spawn one cell at a time swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, caemitterlayer

I am trying to make it so my CAEmitterLayer object only spawn one cell at time. Once the cell lifetime expires, I want to spawn the next and so on. The reason for this is because they keep overlapping causing it to look awful.

I tried apples documentation and couldn't find anything useful.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caemitterlayer

```
func setUpEmitter(){
    let emitter = CAEmitterLayer()
    emitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
    emitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2)
    emitter.emitterShape = CAEmitterLayerEmitterShape.line
    emitter.emitterCells = generateEmitterCells()
    view.layer.insertSublayer(emitter, at: 0)
    // TutorialView.layer.addSublayer(emitter)

}

func generateEmitterCells() -> [CAEmitterCell]{
    var cells = [CAEmitterCell]()

    let cell = CAEmitterCell()
    cell.contents = UIImage(named: "startVCversion3")!.cgImage
    cell.birthRate = 0.2
    cell.lifetime = 100
    cell.velocity = CGFloat(55)
    cell.emissionLongitude = (180 * (.pi/180))
    cell.emissionRange = (45 * (.pi/180))
    cell.scale = 1
    cell.scaleRange = 1

    cells.append(cell)
    return cells
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by properly setting the `bithRate` and `lifetime`. `Birthrate` is defined as the number of objects created per second and `lifetime` is the number of seconds an object lives.

A combination such as this one works fine:

```
func generateEmitterCells() -> [CAEmitterCell]{
        var cells = [CAEmitterCell]()
        let cell = CAEmitterCell()
        cell.contents = UIImage(named: "Circle@3x")!.cgImage
        cell.birthRate = 0.5
        cell.lifetime = 2
        cell.velocity = CGFloat(55)
        cell.emissionLongitude = (180 * (.pi/180))
        cell.emissionRange = (45 * (.pi/180))
        cell.scale = 1
        cell.scaleRange = 1

        cells.append(cell)
        return cells
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just a combination of the size, velocity, birthrate and lifetime of the cells. This is a boring stream of completely separate cells:

```
    let cell = CAEmitterCell()
    cell.birthRate = 5
    cell.lifetime = 1
    cell.velocity = 100
```

You, on the other hand, have a very quick birthrate and a very long lifetime:

```
    cell.birthRate = 0.2
    cell.lifetime = 100
```